# Android Crash when calling a method inside a class, without trigger exceptions or errors

Tags: android

I'm facing a really strange problem,

In my App there is a simple Activity which handle some BLE data.

I've made a class to organize and contain this Data, called "VariablesClass".

In this way, in case of Ble Data reading i call a tailormade VariablesClass method passing as parameter the byte[] array received from BLE.

Then in this VariableClass Method i'd like to split the byte in Bits and load boolean variables depending on bits values.

Anyway the problem cames out when i receive a BLE data. The Ble reading callback is triggered and the MainActivity calls VariablesClass method.

This method get's triggered like normally happen but then it stops at the first istruction.

If i set a BreakPoint, and i try to see what happen, the app and the debugger close istantly after this istruction.

If i don't set a BreakPoint, the app doesn't crash, but the BLE reading is not handle and the boolean variables are not loaded with the currect data.

Here's a screen:
[image]

As you can see from the screen the BreakPoints are telling that only the first istruction is going to be executed.

Comment: Is your app (or the library in which this code is..) obfuscated (Proguard)? In this case, breakpoints will not work since 'Pachchetto_Luci_BLE' method name may have been replaced by 'a', 'b', etc

Comment: Have you called Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler in either your application class or the current activity. It's a good way to ensure you can log all exceptions. It may tell you what is really causing the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized i few seconds after this post that the Code didn't correspond to the BreakPoint's code... So i close android studio, i restart my pc, i restart my android device, and now everything works fine... **facepalm*

Thanks for the help anyway.